# GE dryer short in wire

Tags: electrical

The dryer wasn't working. I realized the timer button was broken and wasn't properly turning. I took the back cover off and when I turned it by hand it worked. As I was putting the start button back in, I bumped the timer device and it flipped back and came in contact with the metal edge and I saw it spark.  I cut the wire back, replaced the connection but nothing. Now, the light doesn't even come on. Suggestions?

Comment: You opened up the dryer without unplugging it first?

Comment: Did you check the breaker?

Comment: What model is the dryer?

Comment: 1)the breaker is good. i plugged it back